# data.table move row up

Tags: r, data.table, lag, data-wrangling, shift

Given the following data table:

```
Category <- c('A','A','A','A')                       
Year <- c(0,1,2,3) 
Amount1 <- c(0,100,200,300) 
Amount2 <- c(0,30,40,0) 
dt_1 <- data.table(Category, Year, Amount1, Amount2) 
dt_1
```

how can I shift amount2 by one row obtaining the following table (filling with 0 the last row)

```
Category <- c('A','A','A','A')                       
Year <- c(0,1,2,3) 
Amount1 <- c(0,100,200,300) 
Amount2 <- c(30,40,0,0) 
dt_2 <- data.table(Category, Year, Amount1, Amount2) 
dt_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `data.table::shift()`:

```r
dt_1[, Amount2 := shift(Amount2, type="lead", fill=0)]
#    Category  Year Amount1 Amount2
#      <char> <num>   <num>   <num>
# 1:        A     0       0      30
# 2:        A     1     100      40
# 3:        A     2     200       0
# 4:        A     3     300       0
```

Comment: what if I want to shift in the same way two or more columns, i.e. apply the same transformation to a list of columns.

Comment: You asked to use `data.table`, so something like `nms <- c("Amount1","Amount2"); dt_1[, (nms) := lapply(.SD, shift, type="lead", fill=0), .SDcols=nms]` works.